# Memory stream is always closed ' cannot access a closed stream;

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream, closedxml

trying to implement a simple memorystream like so:

```
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        workbook.SaveAs(stream);
```

however it trips up every single time throwing this exception:

```
ReadTimeout = 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

and

```
writeTimeOut= 'stream.writeTimeOut' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

every single time this happens.

things  i've tried:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
 {
        workbook.SaveAs(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, 0);
 }
```

and

```
await using var stream = new MemoryStream();
```

and also :

```
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
 {
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        workbook.SaveAs(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, 0);
 }
```

but everything yields the same result of 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'

workbook is an IXLWorkbook
any ideas?

when i hover over workbook in debug it reads `'{XLWorkbook(System.IO.MemoryStream)}'`

i am creating my workbook as such:

```
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();

        using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        workbook.SaveAs(stream);
        byte[] content = stream.ToArray();

        return workbook;
```

Comment: What is `workbook`?

Comment: Have you tried `MemoryStream.ToArray()`? That works even if the stream was closed (precisely for circumstances such as you are experiencing)

Comment: @GuruStron workbook is IXLWorkbook

Comment: that seems like a bug in the closedxml library

Comment: not sure about that, it works in other instances

Comment: workbook in debug says: {XLWorkbook(System.IO.MemoryStream)}

Answer (score 2):

Try this, before reading the stream :

`stream.position = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

use stream reader like this:

```
StreamReader sr = null;
try
{
    workbook.SaveAs(stream);
    sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());                           
}
finally
{
    if (sr != null) sr.Dispose();
}
```